# PrintForm component does not print data at its position

Tags: vb.net

Please, I am using VB.Net 2015 with the PrintForm component which prints a DataGridView positioned close to the top of the form with just PrintForm1.Print command . Now, I have a label at the bottom of the form which prints, but does not print at the bottom but prints almost in the middle of the form. I have docked the label at bottom but does not get printed at that location. I have also tried the powerpack printing options of the PrintForm component and that couldn't print it at the desired location either. What could please be the cause? I appreciate your efforts in this matter.

Comment: You'll need to post some code if you want any chance of receiving help.

Comment: You might be better off using a printdocument. I've never had the best of luck trying to use a form as a means to layout a printable document. I guess you could set the PrintAction to PrintToPreview and keep adjusting the size of the form until it looks right in the preview. Most times a form would be longer than the height of your screen on a widescreen monitor. Just keep sizing it and checking it in the preview.